# Setting a sibling node to be a parent in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, integration

I need to transform the following input xml to the needed output format as shown below using xslt,
How can I set <BTAT_MEASUREMENTSet> to be the Parent of  as the needed output using xslt ?, it's always the at the second level of the message after the root so the relative postion from the root is constant

```
**Input:**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncBTAT_MEASUREMENT
    xmlns="http://www.llll.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2021-03-24T15:39:55+00:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="176416166003958143562">
    <BTAT_MEASUREMENTSet></BTAT_MEASUREMENTSet>
    <MEASUREPOINT action="AddChange">
        <BTATMBO>MEASUREMENT</BTATMBO>
        <ORGID>TAL3-DE</ORGID>
        <POINTNUM>TEMP</POINTNUM>
        <SITEID>TAL3</SITEID>
        <MEASUREMENT>
            <ASSETNUM>2403871\PPC</ASSETNUM>
            <MEASUREDATE>2020-06-16T06:47:07+00:00</MEASUREDATE>
            <MEASUREMENTID/>
            <MEASUREMENTVALUE>20.0</MEASUREMENTVALUE>
            <METERNAME>TIME-MIN-001</METERNAME>
        </MEASUREMENT>
    </MEASUREPOINT>
</SyncBTAT_MEASUREMENT>

**Needed Output:**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncBTAT_MEASUREMENT
    xmlns="http://www.llll.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2021-03-24T15:39:55+00:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="176416166003958143562">
 <BTAT_MEASUREMENTSet>
    <MEASUREPOINT action="AddChange">
        <BTATMBO>MEASUREMENT</BTATMBO>
        <ORGID>TAL3-DE</ORGID>
        <POINTNUM>TEMP</POINTNUM>
        <SITEID>TAL3</SITEID>
        <MEASUREMENT>
            <ASSETNUM>2403871\PPC</ASSETNUM>
            <MEASUREDATE>2020-06-16T06:47:07+00:00</MEASUREDATE>
            <MEASUREMENTID/>
            <MEASUREMENTVALUE>20.0</MEASUREMENTVALUE>
            <METERNAME>TIME-MIN-001</METERNAME>
        </MEASUREMENT>
    </MEASUREPOINT>
  </BTAT_MEASUREMENTSet>
</SyncBTAT_MEASUREMENT>
```

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Hi Michael, Yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the name of the element you want to be the parent starts with `BTAT_`, and that it has no sibling element whose name also starts with `BTAT_`, then you could do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'BTAT')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../* except self::*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming you don't know the name of any elements in the input  XML, incl. the root element - otherwise it could be simpler.

Comment: <CHILD_1> is just a placeholder not a constant

Comment: Then edit your question and explain exactly how to identify it, if its name is not known.

Comment: it's name always starts with "BTAT_" and it's always at the second level from the root, i just need it to wrap around it's sibling while keeping all the attributes and data the same as the source xml

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, you're a guru !, can't upvote because it's my first post here on stackoverflow, thrilled to see how helpful the community is.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the attributes off screen. I have added an instruction to copy them.